# AFNetworking: enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations issue with completion block

Tags: iphone, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, afnetworking

I use this AFNetworking method to start multiple requests at once:

```
- (void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:(NSArray *)operations 
                              progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock 
                            completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock
```

One of them is a `AFJSONRequestOperation`. The problem is that the success-block of this JSON operation is executed after the completion-block of the batch. The reason is: `AFJSONRequestOperation` has an internal dispatch queue for JSON processing. So the JSON data is still in processing while the completion block is called.

Question: How can execute code in the completion block **after** the success block of the JSON operation has been called?

I tried to dispatch a code block on the main queue but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, the simplest solution might be just to move your processing code from the success block of each operation to the completion block of the whole batch.

You have the `NSArray *operations` available in the completion block, you can iterate through the operations and look for:

```
for(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation in operations){
   if(operation.response.statusCode == 200){
      //Do something with the response
   }else{
     //Handle the failure
   }
}
```

You also have the url address for each operation available through the `operation.request.URL` property if you need to preform different actions

Comment: OP said the json is still unprocessed when completion is called, so this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking. So this answer is not helping me.

Comment: Oh right i misread. As for your issue, there might be a patch soon if you can wait for it. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/362

Answer (score 0):

You can move your Json operation to the beginning of the queue, and then add a dependency so that another operation can only start after the json operation finishes:

```
    [lastOperation addDependency:jsonOperation]
```

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: i guess something like this:             if (previousOperation) { [operation addDependency:previousOperation]; } previousOperation = operation; [operations addObject:operation]; it's didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no easy way to do exactly what the OP requests, so here are some easy workarounds.

A rather blunt strategy would be to use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` instead of `AFJSONRequestOperation` and then convert the response using `NSJSONSerialization`.

So the success block of the operation would look like

```
  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
              NSError *error ;
              id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject 
                                            options:kNilOptions error:&error] ;
              ... 
            }
```

Caveats would apply - for large JSON responses this is potentially blocking code, and some of the AFNetworking workarounds to `NSJSONSerialization` issues would not apply.  But this would get you going.

**Update:** The first commenter below suggests using `AFJSONRequestOperation` and calling `responseJSON` on it in the batch completion block.  I'm good with that if your situation allows it. In my current use case it complicates my code somewhat (I'm using a mixed set of JSON calls, so the code is cleaner if I can keep it in a `success` block directly associated with the operation).

Comment: It would make more sense to use the JSON operation, and just call `responseJSON` on it in the batch completion block. This method returns synchronously. This provides the behavior the OP wants without the caveats you mention.